¿Cómo leer desde python un archivo de excel que está en la web sin necesidad de hacer la descarga?
Estoy tratando de automatizar la descarga del archivo más actual de este enlace, donde al rastrear el archivo que necesito me lleva al siguiente enlace de descarga https://www.dane.gov.co/files/operaciones/IPI/anex-IPI-ene2024.xlsx. Sin embargo, no quiero descargar el archivo en local sino leerlo directamente en python para poderlo llevar mediante un azure function a un storage en azure.
Nota: Usé selenium para hacer la descarga, pero esto no es una opción para mí porque no es ejecutable dentro del entorno de las azure function debido a la carencia de servidor
Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda o un posible enfoque que le pueda dar a este problema.

En vez de selenium puedes utilizar requests que te permite hacer solicitudes a una url y obtener el contenido de la página.
Aparte también he utilizado pandas, para leer el contenido del archivo Excel y convertirlo en un DataFrame, e io.BitesIO, que permite tratar datos binarios en memoria como si fueran archivos. En este caso, se utiliza para crear un objeto que simula un archivo de bytes a partir del contenido de la respuesta HTTP; con esto evitamos tener que descargar el archivo.
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://www.dane.gov.co/files/operaciones/IPI/anex-IPI-ene2024.xlsx"

# Obtener el contenido del archivo
response = requests.get(url)

# Verificar si la solicitud fue exitosa
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Leer el contenido del archivo Excel en un DataFrame de pandas
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(BytesIO(response.content))

    # Obtener las hojas del Excel
    sheets = xls.sheet_names
    
    # Leer la hoja de Excel deseada (si no se especifica 'sheet_name' escogerá la primera por defecto)
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheets[1])
    
    # Modifica el DataFrame a tus necesidades
    print(df.to_dict())

else:
    print("Error al obtener el archivo:", response.status_code)

